# sound pitch-shifting in real time using appcelerator

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile, pitch, pitch-shifting

I'm a complete newbie at Appcelerator's Titanium SDK, so I apologize in advance if this question has an obvious answer.

Is there any way to change a sound's pitch in real-time using appcelerator? Is there a module that can do that?

When looking for the answer, I found out about some objective-c libraries (dirac-2, for example) that can do that. Is there any way to interface to such libraries through Titanium without a dedicated module?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I found a module - Zero Latency Sound - that can control a sample pitch in real time.

https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/891?1475082272

Also, this module's support is commendable.